# Require input for data range to allow disable button to run

Tags: html, angularjs

I've got a data range picker which is used to help my table in order to specify a range:

HTML:

```
<form name="reportTable">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="daterange"
               class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 control-label no-padding-right">Date Range:
        </label>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 no-padding-right">
            <div class="input-group date">
                <input class="form-control date-picker" type="text"
                       id="daterange" name="daterange"
                       required/>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 no-padding-right">
            <button class="btn btn-blue" ng-disabled="reportTable.$invalid"
                    ng-click="outputReport()">
                Run
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The context is currently when you run it, it will automatically grab the information related to the dates. With or without specifying the actual date range since it seems to do it automatically. I would like to prevent that, so the user has to enter the range in order it to search. However, I also thought, they need to enter in the date range before clicking the run button hence the idea of disabling it.

No matter what way I do it, I can't seem to get the button to actually be disabled. I've been looking at online examples and I assume it's missing something small but I cannot work it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `<input>` needs a `ng-model` directive in order to be registered with the ngFormController. Also it is likely that whatever date range picker library the code uses is not integrated with the AngularJS framework.